# How to stop an editext being editable

Tags: android

I have an editext which populates on the click of a button.

The problem is when I load android the cursor is allowing this editext to be editable.

I need the edittext not be editable and only update onclick. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tommy.... You can change the text in the onClick handler using setText. Here is some sample code for enabling or disabling editing dynamically:

given

```
private boolean isProhibitEditPassword= false;
```

You can do:

```
     if (cbProhibitEditPW.isChecked()) { // disable editing password
            editTextPassword.setFocusable(false);
            editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            editTextPassword.setClickable(false);
            isProhibitEditPassword= true;
        }
        else { // enable editing of password
            editTextPassword.setFocusable(true);
            editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            editTextPassword.setClickable(true);
            isProhibitEditPassword= false;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks JAL, but how will this stop the editext being editable when the application loads?

Comment: @Tommy. I set the android:editable to false, but this gives the user the false sense that they can edit the view. In your onCreate just programmatically set the three text properties that I posted to false. And then try it! This is production code.